# Why is the sqrt of a matrix different to ^0.5

Tags: matrices, matlab, square-numbers

If `H = [4 4; 4 4]`

Why is `sqrt(H)=[2 2; 2 2]`

And, `(H)^0.5=[1.4142 1.4142; 1.4142 1.4142]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, it's taking the square root of each element. In the second case, it's determining the matrix that, when multiplied by itself, gives $H$, i.e., the "square root" of $H$.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/techdoc/ref/sqrt.html) of the `sqrt()` function, we see (emphasis mine):

> `B = sqrt(X)` returns the square root of **each element** of the array `X`.

So since $\sqrt 4 = 2$, that's what you get.

Reading further on that page, we find

> See `sqrtm` for the matrix square root.

which is probably the one you actually expected.